# How do I display/print a string in a comma-separated array value?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jlabel

I am using a `JFrame` implementing `ActionListener`. My goal is every time a user clicks on the `JButton`, I have to remove and replace the quotes with the next quote (per comma). The last quote would then return back to the first quote. A quote will be displayed every time the button is clicked. I am stuck on how I can do that under `actionPerformed`.

This is what I have so far:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JButton b = new JButton("Press to change fact");
    JLabel fact = new JLabel();
    String[] quotes = new String[]{"Quote1 Goes Here",
            "Quote2 Goes Here",
            "Quote3 Goes Here",
            "Quote 4 Goes Here",
            "Quote 5 Goes Here",
            "Quote 6 Goes Here",
    };

    int counter = 0;
    int MAX = 6;

    public JFacts() {
        super("RANDOM QUOTES");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(flow);
        add(b);
        // STRING QUOTES WILL DISPLAY HERE
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFacts rFrame = new JFacts();
        rFrame.setSize(440, 100);
        rFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;
        if(counter == MAX) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to do a bit more work here.  You don't even set up the JFrame properly.  First try to get the JLabel to display, after that you'll be in a better spot to change text.

Comment: @markspace Sadly, I have to use JFrame as part of the assignment prompt I'm trying to do for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this can be achieved with this if condition logic

```
              if (counter >= quotes.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
```

We are increasing the index every button click and displaying the array elements until `counter >= quotes.length` then return counter to 0 so it can start again

Code

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                
                System.out.println(quotes[counter++]);
                //or
                fact.setText(quotes[counter++]);

                if (counter >= quotes.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

Full code

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JButton b = new JButton("Press to change fact");
    JLabel fact = new JLabel();
    String[] quotes = new String[]{"Quote1 Goes Here",
            "Quote2 Goes Here",
            "Quote3 Goes Here",
            "Quote 4 Goes Here",
            "Quote 5 Goes Here",
            "Quote 6 Goes Here",
    };

    int counter = 0;
    int MAX = 6;

    public Main() {
        super("RANDOM QUOTES");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(flow);
        add(b);
        add(fact);
        fact.setText(quotes[0]);
        // STRING QUOTES WILL DISPLAY HERE
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




                fact.setText(quotes[counter++]);
//                System.out.println(quotes[counter++]);

                if (counter >= quotes.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }


            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main rFrame = new Main();
        rFrame.setSize(440, 100);
        rFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

A simple `output` to test that the program is working you can test it on your `JLabel fact`

```
Quote1 Goes Here
Quote2 Goes Here
Quote3 Goes Here
Quote 4 Goes Here
Quote 5 Goes Here
Quote 6 Goes Here
Quote1 Goes Here
Quote2 Goes Here
Quote3 Goes Here
Quote 4 Goes Here
```